# Netsuite Saved Transaction Search formula error

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I'm trying to get the value counting the number of Sales Orders and multiplying it by the credit limit it has but it returns an error.

I've Grouped by Name and I have a SUM before this:

COUNT({tranid})*{customermain.creditlimit}

I get to "An unexpected has occurred" screen and can't even access the results

Answer (score 0):

Probably this:

COUNT({tranid})* nvl({customermain.creditlimit},0)

Also including an aggregate function inside a summarized column changes how Netsuite handles the summary.

if the above doesn't fix your issue then try making the column's summary function Average and change your formula to:

SUM(COUNT({tranid})* nvl({customermain.creditlimit},0))

Comment: With the first option the error keeps comming and, the second one allows me to execute but in the formula column returns invalid expression